# Azure KUDU deployment ignores project setting when deploy.cmd is specified

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have a custom .deployment file in my nodeJS repo that looks like this:

```
[config]
project = src/portal
command = deploy.cmd
```

If I remove the `command` setting, the `project` setting is respected. However, I need the custom deploy script to execute some bower and grunt commands. Whenever I add the `command` parameter back in, Azure/KUDU seems to ignore the `project` setting. I have reverted to the default deploy.cmd script generated using `azure site deploymentscript --node` to ensure that my customizations aren't the issue. The problem remains. Am I missing something?

For reference, here's the KUDU output from azure:

```
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '3f92585db0'.
remote: Running custom deployment command...
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling node.js deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
remote: Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
remote: The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version  constraints.
remote: The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.10.32.
remote: Finished successfully.
remote: Deployment successful.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, when you have a custom deployment script you have **full** control over the deployment and so the `project` property has no meaning.

If you need a different project simply update the custom deployment script with what you need.

Comment: I finally figured this out, but I didn't find any clear documentation to this effect. I was able to correct the problem by modifying the DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE variable in the deploy.cmd script as necessary.

Comment: @Chris Can you please elaborate how you fixed this? I've run into this same problem. Thanks!

Comment: In the deploy.cmd script, there is a line `SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.` I changed it to `SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.\<path_to_folder_containing_app.js>`