# Programatically set app setting / env variable during Azure (Kudu) deployment

Tags: azure, npm, asp.net-mvc-5, gulp, bower

## Summary

I'm trying to deploy an MVC5 web app to Azure. I need to set WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION programatically to ensure all configuration is atomically contained in the repo. When I try to set that app setting / env variable in `.deployment` or `deploy.cmd`, it gets ignored by the deployment. Why?

## Background

My web app uses bower for client-side libraries, and a simple gulp script to place the minimized libs in a target folder. My cshtml files then consume them from said target folder.

Per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591913/1876622), I've brought down the deployment script (`.deployment` and `deploy.cmd`) from Azure and tweaked it to install bower.

> Then download your custom deployment script. if you go to https://.scm.azurewebsites.net then click on Tools -> Download custom deployment script or just download it from D:\home\deployment\tools

My research then showed that npm is available by default in Azure web app deployments, and the bower package is pre-installed, but gulp isn't. So I need to add 3 custom commands to the deployment scripts:

1. npm install (required to make gulp available)
2. bower install (pulls down the client-side libs)
3. gulp (pipelines the client-side libs)

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412935/npm-3-x-install-fails-on-rename-long-paths-in-windows-azure), The problem I'm facing is that node (and therefore npm) being used are an old version. The `npm install` command is resulting in filenames that are too long, which is a known issue in older versions of npm.

Per [this set of Kudu runtime settings](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#runtime-settings), I'm trying to set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to **6.7.0** (the latest at the time of this question), because that would ensure that the latest npm also runs.

**Here's where my problem occurs.** In `deploy.cmd`, before running `npm install`, I add a line `set WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 6.7.0` (I've tried variations, including with quotes, without spaces around the equal sign, with `setlocal`, etc.) I `echo %WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION%` on either side of setting the variable. The output before and after is always **4.4.7**.

I tried it in `.deployment` as well, to no avail. I even tried changing the position (sometimes before `command = deploy.cmd` and sometimes after).

From what I can decipher off the net, at least *one* of my methods above should work... **Why can't I set this app setting / env variable in the deployment script?**

## Update

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445638/azure-kudu-deployment-ignores-project-setting-when-deploy-cmd-is-specified), I can't set the app settings in the .deployment file. This differs from other articles on the net, but it still doesn't explain why SET isn't working in the deploy.cmd file.

## Files

**.deployment**

```
[config]
;Change node version to change npm version to avoid long-file-name situations
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 6.7.0
command = deploy.cmd
```

**deploy.cmd**

```
(REDACTED - default stuff)
echo :: 4. NPM Install (borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480274/how-do-i-run-gulp-js-in-my-asp-net-core-project-when-deploying-to-azure-using-gi)
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  :: Set the node version. Tried this in .deployment, but that didn't work.
  :: HELP! Why isn't this working???
  echo %WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION% before set
  :: Output: "4.4.7 before set"
  SET WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=6.7.0
  echo %WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION% after set
  :: Output: "4.4.7 after set"
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd npm install
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

echo :: 5. Bower Install (borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591913/1876622)
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd bower install
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

echo :: 6. Run Gulp (borrowed from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/08/12/run-npm-bower-composer-gulp-grunt-in-azure-app-services-during-deployment/)
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\gulpfile.js" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd gulp
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that when I created the Azure web app, it pre-set the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION in the portal (portal.azure.com).  So the UI was superseding my programmatic requests to set the app setting.

After deleting that app setting in the portal (below is a screenshot after removing the setting), I tried deploying again by setting the env var in the .deployment file only... **success!**

[image]

**.deployment**

```
[config]
;Change node version to change npm version to avoid long-file-name situations https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/
;Make sure to delete the value in portal.azure.com > Application settings > App settings... because that will override this
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 6.7.0
command = deploy.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why comes from the CMD.EXE documentation.

> Delayed environment variable expansion is NOT enabled by default.
>
> /V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
>           delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
>           variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
>           at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
>           loop.

Because `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is already set it doesn't re-intreprete it when executing the echo statements.  Add this around the top `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` then try `echo !WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION! after set` instead.